# Displaying Blob PDF in Edge/IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, pdf, cors, blob, microsoft-edge

I have a django app (from which I get some html as a client), and a base64-encoded PDF which needs to be displayed. I've tried multiple approaches, which work as expected in Chrome/Firefox.

I'm working with django, so there will be some templates and some JavaScript.

*`pdf_preview_embed` is a div*

#### Embed DataURL

```html
<embed width=100% height=100% type="application/pdf" src="data:application/pdf;base64, {{ pdf }}"></embed>
```

Unacceptable solution, because it may require inlining megs of data. Works in IE11 under Windows 7, doesn't work on Edge and IE11 under Windows 10.

#### Embed Blob

[base64binary implementation](https://github.com/danguer/blog-examples/blob/master/js/base64-binary.js)

```js
var blob = new Blob( [Base64Binary.decode(pdf)], {'type': 'application/pdf'} );
pdfURL = URL.createObjectURL( blob );
$('#pdf_preview_embed').html(
    '<embed width=100% height=100% type="application/pdf" src="'+pdfURL+'"></embed>'
);
```

Also does not work in Edge and IE11.

#### <iframe> Blob

```js
$('#pdf_preview_embed').html(
    '<iframe src="'+pdfURL+'" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>'
);
```

Edge claims it can't open pdf, and IE11 doesn't show anything.

#### Actually using pdf.js to display the pdf

Now here something happens: I found out the blob url origin is `null`, instead of the application for Edge and IE11, causing pdf.js to refuse opening it. Server CORS is configured to allow all origins. I am a bit lost.

Comment: Feed your PDF data to PDF.js as is without converting it to BASE64 or Blob (you might need to change viewer.html to handle your transport method)

Comment: I can't add the code to link, url gets too long!

Comment: I manager to solve it using your suggestion, but the issue of blob origin in Edge/IE11 remains unresolved.

Comment: PDF.js is using polyfill for URL object constructor (which IE11 does not have) -- probably polyfill needs to fixed. (Blob URL usually has unorthodox way of specifying its origin)

Comment: I've struggled to find much information on this, but just recently came to the same conclusion that almost exactly 1 year from your original question that Edge just isn't generating appropriate blob urls. That is when using window.URL.createObjectURL(someblob) you end up with a URL that just has 'blob:somedatahere' where in chrome/firefox you get 'blob:https://whatever.com/somedatahere'. This is not only an issue for displaying PDFs within an embed (what I was originally attempting), but it is also blocking the popout into an external window as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A cross-browser workaround to have an iframe of PDF.js load a blob of a PDF via the iframe URI.

An example of a standard usage case blob URI:

```
/viewer.html?file=blob:19B579EA-5217-41C6-96E4-5D8DF5A5C70B
```

File viewer.js:

within function webViewerOpenFileViaURL:

change line from:

```
if (file && file.lastIndexOf('file:', 0) === 0) {
```

to:

```
if (file && file.lastIndexOf('file:', 0) === 0 || file && file.lastIndexOf('blob:', 0) === 0) {
```

And to further stop the viewer from breaking when the "origin" is behaving in an IE 11/Edge manner:

within function validateFileURL:

change line from:

```
if (fileOrigin !== viewerOrigin) {
```

to:

```
if (fileOrigin != "null" && fileOrigin !== viewerOrigin) {
```

Now FF, Chrome, IE 11, and Edge all display the PDF in a viewer in the iframe passed via standard blob URI in the URL.

Comment: I try your code. but can't load pdf data in viewer.html

Answer (score 0):

Blob URLs will not work in IE11 due to security restrictions!

Comment: Yes, they will, the behavior just differs from the other major browsers, so IE11 must be pampered for it to work.