# Render byte array as pdf using Javascript inside iframe Internet Explorer/Edge

Tags: javascript, pdf, internet-explorer, iframe, bytestream

I have a byte array(which was converted from an original PDF file) returned from an http post method. My requirement is to render the original PDF inside an iframe , i use angular 1.x with IE/Edge browser.

Answer (score 0):

IE and Microsoft Edge [don't support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri) iframe with data url as src attribute. So you can't display blob data of pdf directly in an iframe in IE or Microsoft Edge.

The workaround is to use [`msSaveOrOpenBlob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/hh772332(v=vs.85)) to handle blobs in IE and Microsoft Edge to open the pdf or using [PDF.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/) to render it in browsers using `<canvas>`. You could refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24535799/pdf-js-and-viewer-js-pass-a-stream-or-blob-to-the-viewer) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38505424/displaying-blob-pdf-in-edge-ie11) for more information about using PDF.js.

Answer (score 0):

I had put a similar question here. The truth is you cannot display PDF directly in IE/Microsoft Edge directly as a blob, even if you use a pdf viewer. The only solution you can use is `msSaveOrOpenBlob()`:

`navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob_url);`

if you want, you can perform the action in a new window:

`window.open(navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob_url))`

This will give you a prompt to either open or save the file. If you click the open button, it will download a local copy of the file and open it, which is possible in IE/Edge. If you are so adamant that you need to view the file, I suggest you use Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox, both of which can open the file directly. Firefox has its own PDF Viewer.

Happy Coding!! :)